# UTF-8 and Jinja when template inheritance

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, jinja2

I am using template inheritance with jinja. Some of my child templates have unicode characters and when trying to render within the parent template I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 292: invalid continuation byte
```

If I do not use template inheritance, and just render everything on the same file I do not get any errors.
Is there a way I can decode the child template as UTF-8, or what solution would you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: it's not utf-8, so you can't decode it as utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found your answer alredy, but try adding the following to your template.

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data>
```